# Function error - Use of undefined constant ‘pre_get_posts’ - assumed '‘pre_get_posts’'

Tags: custom-post-types

On my functions I have this code to display categories archive for custom posts.

```
function add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars[‘suppress_filters’] 
) ) {

// Get all your post types
$post_types = get_post_types();

$query->set( ‘post_type’, $post_types );
return $query;
}
}
add_filter( ‘pre_get_posts’, ‘add_custom_types_to_tax’ );
```

But I am getting the following error messages:

Use of undefined constant ‘pre_get_posts’ - assumed '‘pre_get_posts’'

Use of undefined constant ‘add_custom_types_to_tax’ - assumed '‘add_custom_types_to_tax’'

How to I get this to work without the errors?

Comment: hmmm can you indent your code? Unformatted code can lead to strange errors as missing braces and other things are easily missed. As an aside, use an editor with good syntax highlighting, and your problem should become super obvious

Answer (score 6):

Those look like curly apostrophes, not straight... try changing them to straight (all of them in your code) like this:

```
function add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
    if ( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        // Get all your post types
        $post_types = get_post_types();
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_types_to_tax' );
```

Comment: @Tim G this does sometimes happen when you copy/paste some code from online articles - always double-check that you are using the proper straight  single ' and double " quotes in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed the apostrophes, I have replaced and now works correctly.

Comment: np, would you mind hitting the check mark to set as answered?